# SF4/WWebpack - Javascript Function Is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack

I'm using Symfony's WebPack.Encore bundle and I realize one thing is that for a single button onclick = function (), my function is not defined, whereas if I put it in a document.ready, it works.
Can you explain to me how to make this function call on an onclick?

```
// file.js
function newInvLine(){
  alert("Hi");
}

// html
<a href="#" onclick="newInvLine();">TEST</a>
```

My webpack.config

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
// public path used by the web server to access the output path
.setPublicPath('/public/build')
// only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
//.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

/*
 * ENTRY CONFIG
 *
 * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
 * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
 *
 * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
 * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
 */
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
.addEntry('find_city_by_cp', './assets/js/find_city_by_cp.js')
.addEntry('calculSimulateur', './assets/js/file.js')
//.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
//.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

/*
 * FEATURE CONFIG
 *
 * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
 * list of features, see:
 * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
 */
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.enableBuildNotifications()
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
// enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
.enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

// enables Sass/SCSS support
.enableSassLoader()

// uncomment if you use TypeScript
//.enableTypeScriptLoader()

// uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not 'connected' to your browser window anymore, the handler changed.

This means we have to make the 'window' object aware of your new function.

```
window.newInvLine = function() {
  alert("Hi");
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, even as I do as indicated, he tells me that the function is not defined

Comment: Can you use that function with the Chrome Console? What about window.newInvLine()?

Comment: Same got 'Uncaught ReferenceError: newInvLine is not defined'
I have just make like you said and re-compiling

Comment: Hmm, it worked for my in my projects. Can you show us your js file?

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `global` constant that you can use.  It will make the function available globally. Example:

```
const dt = require('datatables.net-responsive-bs');
global.dt = dt;
```